# Calcular meses en Javascript

Tags: javascript

¿Alguna manera de calcular 4 meses posteriores exactos a una fecha obtenida de un string, por ejemplo "17/12/2017"?

Gracias de antemano!

Comment: Deberías poner el código que has intentado hacer, para corregir el error en lugar de esperar la solución

Answer (score 1):

Tienes dos problemas:

**Transformar una cadena en un String**

Para tu ejemplo podrías uasar algo como esto. Sencillo y específico. Si quieres algo más genérico deberías irte a algún tipo de solución por librería.

```
var strDate = "17/12/2017";
var dateParts = strDate.split("/");

var date = new Date(dateParts[2], (dateParts[1] - 1), dateParts[0]);
```

**Añadir meses a una fecha**

Aquí te dejo un ejemplo en el que se suman tres meses a la fecha 31 de Enero de 2009

```
var jan312009 = new Date(2009, 0, 31);
var eightMonthsFromJan312009  = jan312009.setMonth(jan312009.getMonth()+3);
```

Un saludo